# Jetstream Browser Sessions does not list devices – Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-jetstream

In my dev environment, **Log out other browser sessions**’ feature works well. However, in the production environment,  **Log out other browser sessions**’ feature doesn’t work. It does not display the devices either.

resources/views/profile/logout-other-browser-sessions-form.blade.php

```
<x-jet-action-section>
    <x-slot name="title">
        {{ __('Browser Sessions') }}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="description">
        {{ __('Manage and log out your active sessions on other browsers and devices.') }}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="content">
        <div class="max-w-xl text-sm text-gray-600">
            {{ __('If necessary, you may log out of all of your other browser sessions across all of your devices. Some of your recent sessions are listed below; however, this list may not be exhaustive. If you feel your account has been compromised, you should also update your password.') }}
        </div>
        @if (count($this->sessions) > 0)
          There are = {{ count($this->sessions) }}
        @else
          There are NO sessions
        @endif
        @if (count($this->sessions) > 0)
        ...
```

Dev environment
[It shows two devices logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AeLo.png)

Prod environment
[There are two devices logged in but it does not show any of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7aOV.png)

Does anyone have any idea why this happen?

Comment: You need to SESSION_DRIVER to "database" in your .env file.

Comment: Thank you very much _Dejan Prole_. In addition, I ran `$ php artisan config:cache`. It is working now.